# React - event.target.id/name undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, function

I'm using react-bootstrap-typeahead.

```
{this.state.data.map((item, index) => {
   return (
           <Typeahead
             key={index}
             id={index}
             name={index}
             labelKey="event"
             options={this.state.matches}
             onChange={this.onChangeEvent}
             onInputChange={this.onChange}
           />
   );
}
```

This then returns undefined because name and id isn't in event.target

```
onChange = (text, event) => {
        console.log(event.target.id) //event.target.name undefined aswell
}
```

I also tried doing something like this in the array map

```
onInputChange={this.onChange + '1'}
or
onInputChange={this.onChange + index}
```

Is that possible in some way, is my syntax off?

My question is, how do I retrieve the index of the item in an onChange handler in the onInputChange attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the `index`, into the `onChange` function like the code below. In this way every time Input changes, the `onChange` function will pass `event` and `index` as parameters.

```
onInputChange={(e) => { this.onChange(e, index) }}

.......

onChange = (event, index) => {
        console.log(event.target.id)
}
```

Comment: Can I do like this to set the state? On index 0 I want state to be event0 here. onInputChangeEvent = (label, index) => {
        this.setState({ 'event' + index: label })
    }